# Contract deployment with "truffle-contract"

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, nodejs, truffle-deployment

My purpose is deploying a smart contract to a private network with Node-js. I work on Truffle and Ganache. I tried it with "truffle-contract". But in deploying process an error occurs. My contract name is "Deploy".

Command i used to deploy: `myContract.deploy().send(...);`.

The error: `TypeError: myContract.deploy is not a function`.

I don't know what is the problem. Please provide an appropriate code.

app.js:

```
var fs=require("fs");
var solc=require("solc");
var contract=require("truffle-contract");
var Web3=require('web3');
var web3=new Web3('ws://127.0.0.1:8545');
var address="0xfE72f8B082CF099715785d23FBeaed9272F27559";
var DeployJson=fs.readFileSync("E:/Deploy/build/contracts/Deploy.json");
var DeployJs=JSON.parse(DeployJson);
var DeployAbi=DeployJs.abi;
var contract=require("truffle-contract");
var myContract=contract({abi: DeployAbi, unlinked_binary:"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"});
     myContract.setProvider(web3);
     myContract.deploy().send({from:address, gas:1000000, gasPrice:200});
```

Comment: Having a quick look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-contract show no `deploy` function. Shouldn't it be `deployed()`?

Comment: That says it should be `new()` but i don't usage of `new()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `deploy` method in the API provided by `require('truffle-contract')`.

Given `truffleContract = require('truffle-contract')`, you need to do something like this:

```
const myContract = truffleContract({abi: ..., unlinked_binary: ...});
const block = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
myContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
myContract.defaults({from: address, gas: block.gasLimit});
const myInstance = await myContract.new({from: address, gas: 1000000, gasPrice: 200});
return myInstance;
```

You'll have to do it inside an `async` function of course.

BTW, a `gasPrice` of 200 is extremely low.

You might wanna change it to something like `"2e9"` (2 gwei)...

Answer (score 2):

Using below code you can deploy your contract using truffle-contract.

```
const contract = require('truffle-contract');
const DeployJson = fs.readFileSync("E:/Deploy/build/contracts/Deploy.json");
const DeployContract = contract(DeployJson);
DeployContract.setNetwork('network_id');

// Unlock the account from which you want to deploy the contract
await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.coinbase, 'password', 'duration');
const contractInstance = await DeployContract.new({
    from: web3.eth.coinbase,
    gas: 8000000
})
```

Comment: Your work seems to be incomplete. You didn't use the contract binary and  an error emerges: `Error: Contract error: contract binary not set. Can't deploy new instance.`

Comment: @A.Kiakojouri, Thank you for pointing that out, it should be await DeployContract.new(DeployContract.bytecode, ... }). This will fix it.